# How to find element by two attributes

Tags: angularjs, protractor, angularjs-e2e

I have radio buttons like, how can I get the second one clicked finding first by `ng-model` then `ng-value`:

```
<input type="radio" ng-model="vm.ist.educationVsInternship" ng-value=false />

<input type="radio" ng-model="vm.ist.educationVsInternship" ng-value=true />
```

I tried something like

```
element(by.model('vm.ist.educationVsInternship')).all(by.css('[ng-value=true]')).click();
```

says and does not click any of them

```
more than one element found for locator by.model("vm.ist.educationVsInternship") - the first result will be used
```

and this:

```
element(by.model('vm.ist.educationVsInternship')).element(by.css('[ng-value=true]')).click();
```

which gives me the following error message:

> Failed: No element found using locator: By.cssSelector("[ng-value=true]")

Comment: try to modify selector this way: element(by.model('vm.ist.educationVsInternship')).$('input[ng-value=true]').click();

Comment: @isherwood Don't you think it is easier to find issue in google  if `protractor`keyword is in the header?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130208/247976

Comment: @isherwood short and cool answer but it is discussable as closing question because of dublicate. And I don't agree

Comment: So roll back the edit. Better: rewrite your question so you don't have to duplicate what the tags already do. It's just visual clutter otherwise.

Comment: @isherwood What you have done is correct according to community, let's keep this this way. I just want to ask If google is aware about tags?

Comment: Did you read the answer I linked? It's all explained there.

Comment: "Stack Overflow is optimized so that tags are indexed by search engines along with the content of the question. Users are guaranteed to view your tags, and will take them into account when answering your question.

Therefore it is completely unnecessary to force tags into your question titles."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine attribute selectors like this:

```
$('input[ng-model="vm.ist.educationVsInternship"][ng-value="true"]')
```

Comment: That works, thanks a lot. `element(by.css('input[ng-model="vm.ist.educationVsInternship"][ng-value="true"]')).click();` is equivalent I think

Comment: Yes, `$` is a shortcut for `element(by.css())`